# Updating the data of an existing column and copying data with migrations

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-seeding, laravel-schema-builder

Is it possible to add a new column, copy some data to this new column and update the data in another column with a Laravel migration?

I have a table something like this;

| id | item | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ItemOne | 100.00 |
| 2 | ItemTwo | 200.00 |

Now what I need to do is,

1. add a new column, `old_price` to this table
2. copy the values in the `price` column to newly added `old_price` column
3. multiply the values in the `price` column with 5 and update the same column

The new table should look something like this;

| id | item | price | old_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ItemOne | 500.00 | 100.00 |
| 2 | ItemTwo | 1000.00 | 200.00 |

Is it possible to to achieve this with a migration or a seed or something?

This change needs to be done on an application that is already in production so dropping and re-creating the tables is not an option for me here.

Also the `old_price` column is created just to keep a reference of the current values of the `price` column. It **will not** be updated after this and probably will be removed in an later update if everything is going right with the new prices. So I don't need to use any model events to update the column afterwards.

Any help you can give me on this is really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a new migration.

Version 1. create automatically by command:

```
php artisan make:migration add_price_old_to_products_table
```

Version 2. create manually something like this:

**2021_08_18_163618_add_price_old_to_products_table.php**

Manage the content by following the 3 steps in the code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddPriceOldToProductsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        // 1. creating a new column
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // this is just an example, you can change this
            // NOTE: make sure that the type is the same as "price" column
            // for avoiding type conflicts
            $table->decimal('price_old', 10, 2)->nullable();
        });

        // 2. copying the existing column values into new one
        DB::statement("UPDATE products SET price_old = price");

        // 3. update the old/existing column
        // CHANGE YOUR "price" COLUMN HERE...
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('price_old');
        });
    }
}
```

Run that migration for creating a new column:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This worked fine for me.